# PHP8: Undefined symlink() function

Tags: php, php-8

After following the PHP documentation ([symlink](https://php.net/function.symlink)) which is still included in **PHPv8**, I'm still having issues with undefined function call symlink() on **PHPv8.0.10** version.

[image: Demo image]

Comment: Is that code running on your local machine or on a web-hosting service? I've seen some functions such as `symlink` being disabled for security reasons in the past. Check your `php.ini` file to see if the directive `disable_functions` contains `symlink`.

Comment: This code run on a web-hosting service (sorry for that). looks like once I found out it was intentionally disabled for security. Thanks for the input, very helpful for me who is new to this.

Comment: A lot of hosting provider disable functions that interact with the operating system outside of the standard file operations (create, write, read and delete). Some features are also often disabled for performances reasons (such as the GD library).